# How to obtain the LaTeX compilation report by using AUCTeX in Emacs

Tags: emacs, auctex

Can I use Spacemacs with LaTeX layer to compile a LaTeX file and obtain the report as follows:

**Latex Compilation Report(Page: 14)

Error: 0 Warning 8, Bod Boxes: 23**

I normally use WinEdit to compile LaTeX files. Such report with the total number is very helpful for me. But I don't know how to get it in Spacemacs with AUCTeX. Does any one help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the LaTeX compilation report with AUCTeX you should use `C-c C-l`. It will be in a new buffer.

You could also print in a new buffer the first Error/Warning/bad boxes message with `` C-c C-` ``.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. "C-c C-l" is useful, but "C-c C-`" is undefined in my Spacemacs with AUCTex. Is it possible to obtain the total number of the errors/warnings/bad boxes? Some of them are difficult to figure out, but I want to check whether or not the numbers are changed. WinEdt provides this function.

Comment: You can have a list of all error and warning with `M-x TeX-error-overview`. By the way to raise a warning on bad boxes you should use `C-c C-t C-b` (toggle bad boxes).

If you found the answer useful, you can upvote it and accept `:-)`

Comment: Thank you Romain. These commands are useful. I will try them. I accept your answer but i am not able to upvote it. Sorry. :)